Running Coverage in Jupyter Notebook
I am trying to generate a sample coverage.py report in Jupyter Notebook.
Using API, I have managed to run this code:
! pip install coverage

import coverage
import unittest

# Define very basic test case class
class SampleTestUnit(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        result = 1 + 1
        self.assertEqual(2, result)

# Define suite
loader = unittest.TestLoader()
suite = loader.loadTestsFromTestCase(SampleTestUnit)

# Start coverage
cov = coverage.Coverage()
cov.start()

# Running suite
runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
runner.run(suite)

# Stop coverage
cov.stop()
cov.save()

# Print coverage report to console
cov.report()

Run the code in the notebook.
This code, however, ends up with this error:
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.002s

OK
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NoSource                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[5], line 25
     22 cov.save()
     24 # Print coverage report to console
---> 25 cov.report()

File c:\Users\dpura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\coverage\control.py:1084, in Coverage.report(self, morfs, show_missing, ignore_errors, file, omit, include, skip_covered, contexts, skip_empty, precision, sort, output_format)
   1070 with override_config(
   1071     self,
   1072     ignore_errors=ignore_errors,
   (...)
   1081     format=output_format,
   1082 ):
   1083     reporter = SummaryReporter(self)
-> 1084     return reporter.report(morfs, outfile=file)

File c:\Users\dpura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\coverage\report.py:181, in SummaryReporter.report(self, morfs, outfile)
    178 self.outfile = outfile or sys.stdout
    180 self.coverage.get_data().set_query_contexts(self.config.report_contexts)
--> 181 for fr, analysis in get_analysis_to_report(self.coverage, morfs):
    182     self.report_one_file(fr, analysis)
    184 if not self.total.n_files and not self.skipped_count:

File c:\Users\dpura\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\coverage\report_core.py:100, in get_analysis_to_report(coverage, morfs)
...
---> 64     raise NoSource(f"No source for code: '{filename}'.")
     66 # Replace \f because of http://bugs.python.org/issue19035
     67 source_bytes = source_bytes.replace(b"\f", b" ")

NoSource: No source for code: 'C:\Users\dpura\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_34480\3314586203.py'.

In other words: the test suite runs well, but coverage cannot find the file involved in that execution. Is it possible to keep the file somehow in ipythonkernel?
I did try looking for an answer in ChatGPT, but the only answer that works is to convert the notebook to python script and then run it.
